# Make overlapping html and svg based elements respond to click event

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

Is there a way to make both the html based div *and* the SVG based line in the snippet below respond to javascript?

I know of the [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) css property. But it seems to be all or nothing to me - I want both elements to respond to events ...

```css
#main {
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
}

svg {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  stroke: rgb(155, 155, 155);
  stroke-width: 10
}

#box-container {
  display: flex;
}

.box {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: pink;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    Html based boxes should be clickable
  </p>
  <p>
    SVG based line should be clickable
  </p>
</div>
<div id="main">
  <svg>
    <line onClick="alert('line')" x1="0" y1="0" x2="600" y2="100" />
  </svg>
  <div style="display:flex;">
    <div onClick="alert('one')" class="box">
      One
    </div>
    <div onClick="alert('two')" style="margin-left:auto" class="box">
      Two
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [svg path pointer-events - click detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17949547/svg-path-pointer-events-click-detection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
#main {
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
}

svg {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  stroke: rgb(155, 155, 155);
  stroke-width: 10
}

#box-container {
  display: flex;
}

.box {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: pink;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    Html based boxes should be clickable
  </p>
  <p>
    SVG based line should be clickable
  </p>
</div>
<div id="main">
  <svg>
    <line style="pointer-events:all;" onClick="alert('line')" x1="0" y1="0" x2="600" y2="100" />
  </svg>
  <div style="display:flex;">
    <div onClick="alert('one')" class="box">
      One
    </div>
    <div onClick="alert('two')" style="margin-left:auto" class="box">
      Two
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. A little bit of explanation would be nice to have

Answer (score 1):

You can't. But you can trigger click event on another element like this.

```js
function lineClick() {
  alert('line')
  document.querySelector("#one").click()
}
```

```css
#main {
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
}

svg {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  stroke: rgb(155, 155, 155);
  stroke-width: 10
}

#box-container {
  display: flex;
}

.box {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: pink;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    Html based boxes should be clickable
  </p>
  <p>
    SVG based line should be clickable
  </p>
</div>
<div id="main">
  <svg>
    <line onClick="lineClick()" x1="0" y1="0" x2="600" y2="100" />
  </svg>
  <div style="display:flex;">
    <div onClick="alert('one')" class="box" id="one">
      One
    </div>
    <div onClick="alert('two')" style="margin-left:auto" class="box">
      Two
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe I asked the question a bit fuzzy. But I want the two clicks to be separate from each other. A click on the line should not be the same as a click on the box.

Comment: there is a misunderstanding. sorry :)

Answer (score 1):

You can set `svg{pointer-events:none}`(won't respond to mouse events). Next you can give the `line{pointer-events:all}`/(will respond to mouse events). If you need `one` to respond on the same event as the `line` use @dgknca's solution.

```css
#main {
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
}

svg {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  stroke: rgb(155, 155, 155);
  stroke-width: 10;
  pointer-events:none;
}

line{pointer-events:all;}

#box-container {
  display: flex;
}

.box {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: pink;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    Html based boxes should be clickable
  </p>
  <p>
    SVG based line should be clickable
  </p>
</div>
<div id="main">
  <svg>
    <line onClick="alert('line')" x1="0" y1="0" x2="600" y2="100" />
  </svg>
  <div style="display:flex;">
    <div onClick="alert('one')" class="box">
      One
    </div>
    <div onClick="alert('two')" style="margin-left:auto" class="box">
      Two
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a **single** delegated Event handler, you can use `elementsFromPoint(x,y)`

```html
<script>
  function clickHandler(evt) {
    // get all Elements under this X,Y point
    let elements = document.elementsFromPoint(evt.clientX, evt.clientY);
    // disregard the SVG element
    let element = elements[(elements[0].nodeName == "svg") ? 1 : 0];
    console.log(elements);
    console.log(element);
  }
</script>
<style>
  #main {
    position: relative;
    width: 600px;
  }
  svg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    stroke: green;
    stroke-width: 10
  }
  .box {
    width: 200px;
    background-color: pink;
    height: 100px;
  }
</style>
<div id="main" onclick="clickHandler(event)">
  <svg>
    <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="600" y2="100" />
  </svg>
  <div style="display:flex;">
    <div class="box" id=ONE>
      One
    </div>
    <div style="margin-left:auto" class="box" id=TWO>
      Two
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```